# How to update remaining days of all user in firestore from server side?

Tags: java, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I just want to know that how we can update all remaining days of all users in firestore from server side.Is there any need to use firebase CLI and node.js.

Comment: Do you mean remain day for access firestore for your project?

Comment: No , remaining days of their particular plan from now.

Let's say my plan is expiring at 1st march , so how can i calculate days left from this day in background(Server side).

Comment: You would just store the expiry date and calculate how many days remain when you need to use that value.

Comment: No not in that way @BrettJeffreson it must be calculate from server side with current date.

Comment: Did you write any code? Please write some code and try it and then ask the question if you face some problem. By the way, this can be done by storing the start date and time of the user and check every time when the user logs into the app.

Comment: @Pronoy999 how to calculate if user does not logs in app for couples of weeks.So i think it must be calculate from server side from current date.

Comment: When the user is trying to login into to the app, you can query firebase and check whether is it valid or not. If the user is not valid then you can reject the request else accept it. You don't need to store the value. You just need to store the start date and the validity days.

Answer (score 1):

To run periodic updates (on a daily basis) I would suggest a Firebase function which queries the collection and updated the data according to your needs. You can create a http function which can be triggered via URL (you can schedule a CRON job to trigger it) or pubsub function which has it's own scheduling mechanism (It needs a paid Firebase plan).

PubSub example:

```
export scheduledFunctionCrontab =
    functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *').onRun((context) => {
        console.log('This will be run every day at 11:05 AM UTC!');
        //query and update database collection

});
```

Http example:

```
exports.functionName = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    //query and update database collection
});
```

Javascript for updating Firestore in Node.js would be something like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var db = admin.firestore();

async function getDocuments() {
    let docRef = db.collection('<collectionName>');
    const result = await docRef.where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '>=', 'condition')
    .get();
    return result.docs;
}

exports.updateData = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 days').onRun(async context => {
    const documents = await getDocuments();
    for(i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
        documents[i].update({
            timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This might work but the problem is i'm not aware how code in node.js.Can you help in that case?

Comment: Thank you updating your answer but where should mention the calculation part (subtraction from expiry date to current date) and update that particular node with updated value.

Comment: `documents[i].update({ timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});`  updates the value with current timestamp. You can make any calculation you want before updating it. To get the current document timestamp just call `documents[i].timestamp`